# If United States annexed part of another country, would someone born in that place be eligible to run for president?

Tags: united-states, president, constitution, presidential-election, citizenship

For example, if President Trump invaded and claimed Sudbury, Ontario over a dairy dispute, could Alex Trebek run for President in the next election?

Comment: There actually is a precedent case for this: When [the United States annexed Texas in 1845](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_annexation). But I can't find a source right now stating what legal status Texan citizens had after the annexation.

Comment: Based on [the present status of Puerto Ricans](https://www.law.upenn.edu/journals/conlaw/articles/volume11/issue2/Hein11U.Pa.J.Const.L.423(2009).pdf), I would assume that a Texan born before Texas was a state could not serve as president.

Comment: @BrianZ that piece is just one law student's opinion about the present status of Puerto Ricans.  A Supreme Court justice has [offered a different opinion](http://www.cbsnews.com/news/can-a-puerto-rican-be-president-justice-breyer-speculates/) on the question.  Who is more likely to be correct?

Comment: @phoog both are pure speculation. Granted, it's *informed* speculation as both are well versed in the law. But there is no "answer" here. It's a purely hypothetical question.

Comment: Put me in the camp that sees both resolutions as legitimate answers to the question. There is also considerable dispute over when litigation over the eligibility of a candidate to serve as President becomes ripe or moot, and over which forums have jurisdiction to resolve that question. Arguably it is a political question vested in the House of Representatives acting in a quasi-judicial capacity as it receives electoral votes, determines their validity, and then determines who win based upon the electoral votes received. It may be moot after the House decides, and it isn't clear when it's ripe.

Answer (score 11):

Maybe. It depends on the wording of the annexation treaty. Such a treaty would need to be written with explicit wording regarding the establishment of citizenship and eligibility of for holding the office of President of the United States of residents of the annexed territory.

If the treaty writers decide to *stick with tradition*, who knows. For territories annexed to date, the phrase in the treaties that established citizenship read:

> the enjoyment of all these rights, advantages and immunities of citizens of the United States

Since there are no people currently alive who were born in an annexed territory, and no one from an annexed territory ever tried to run for president, there is no precedent that establishes whether this phrasing is sufficient to establish such residents as "natural born" citizens or not.

There have been several annexations throughout the history of the U.S. The annexation treaties contain clauses concerning the citizenship status of residents of annexed territories. For instance, the [Louisiana Purchase](https://www.ourdocuments.gov/doc.php?doc=18&page=transcript) stated it this way:

> Art: III
>
> The inhabitants of the ceded territory shall be incorporated in the
>   Union of the United States and admitted as soon as possible according
>   to the principles of the federal Constitution to the enjoyment of all
>   these rights, advantages and immunities of citizens of the United
>   States, and in the mean time they shall be maintained and protected in
>   the free enjoyment of their liberty, property and the Religion which
>   they profess.

The [Adams-Onus](http://web.archive.org/web/20160923113039/http://www.tamu.edu/faculty/ccbn/dewitt/adamonis.htm) treaty says:

> ARTICLE 6 The Inhabitants of the Territories which His Catholic
>   Majesty cedes to the United States by this Treaty, shall be
>   incorporated in the Union of the United States, as soon as may be
>   consistent with the principle of the Federal Constitution, and
>   admitted to the enjoyment of all the privileges, rights and immunities
>   of the Citizens of the United States.

The [Treaty of Guadalupe Hidalgo](https://www.ourdocuments.gov/doc.php?flash=true&doc=26&page=transcript) refers back to earlier treaties:

> (Article iX): ... With respect to political rights, their condition
>   shall be on an equality with that of the inhabitants of the other
>   territories of the United States; and at least equally good as that of
>   the inhabitants of Louisiana and the Floridas, when these provinces,
>   by transfer from the French Republic and the Crown of Spain, became
>   territories of the United States.

Comment: But note that the office of president requires a very *specific* type of citizenship: that it was obtained from being naturally born here. That said, of course any treaty (I suppose) could grant 'natural born status' to the people (hypothetically, at least).

Comment: @blip, "naturally born", not "naturally born *here*".  You can be naturally born while still being born abroad, usually because your parent was a U.S. citizen

Comment: @JoelFan yes, good point.

Comment: Whoa. the begining of this answer is confused. Article 6 does not make treaties laws on par with consitutional clauses. if it did, then so would "the Laws of the United States which shall be made in Pursuance [of this Consitution]" (a.k.a. federal laws) be on the same level as the constitution, but we all know federal laws can be unconstitutional.

Comment: "Since there are no people currently alive who were born in an annexed territory" Not sure what you count as "annexed", but the Northern Mariana Islands became a US territory in a process lasting from 1978 to 1986. Many people who were born there before it became a US territory are alive today.

Answer (score 0):

No. Alex Trebek was born in Canada. Whether his birth place remained a part of Canada or not wouldn't have much relevance.

That said, I believe this is a purely hypothetical scenario and has never been questioned in court.

Comment: Can you provide some form of evidence that this is correct?

Comment: @BobTheAverage what kind of evidence are you looking for? That's it's purely hypothetical?

Comment: @Blip Any sort of evidence at all. As it stands, this is purely your opinion based on nothing at all.

Comment: @BobTheAverage it's not just my opinion. It's a fact. Trebek was born in Canada. It's also fact that The US Constitution requires that the president be a natural born citizen. I could cite references but these are generally seen as common knowledge.

Comment: @blip but the question is about the definition of natural-born citizen, especially with respect to annexed territories.

Comment: @phoog but as I state, it's *hypothetical*. This would have to be decided by a court case. As since that has yet to happen, there is no "evidence" of a verdict.

Answer (score -1):

Article 2, Section 1 of the U.S. Constitution:
"No Person except a natural born Citizen, or a Citizen of the United States, at the time of the Adoption of this Constitution, shall be eligible to the Office of President;"

This means that the person has to be born a U.S. Citizen; location is irrelevant. Alex Trebek, or any other Canadian-born person, would not be able to run for President if Canada were annexed, because they weren't born as U.S. Citizens.

Comment: Has it been ruled that sentence means 1787 only? Or perhaps a territory entering the nation and it's citizens granted US citizenship could be said to adopt the constitution.

Comment: Location is very relevant when determining who is a natural born citizen.

Comment: @indigochild but only at the time of birth.

Comment: @indigochild, sometimes it isn't... for example under certain conditions, having a U.S. citizen parent establishes citizenship regardless of the place of birth.  That is what made Ted Cruz eligible and would have made Barack Obama eligible even if he had been born abroad

Comment: I feel that Ted Cruz's campaigning for the presidential spot negates this article.